# What is a MediaTypeHeaderValue in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

What is MediaTypeHeaderValue in layman's English?  I read the definition below and did not understand it. Searching for a common, simple glossary definition.

```
"Represents a media-type as defined in the RFC 2616."
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh137959(v%3Dvs.118)

Comment: Google 'Media Type Header value'

Comment: Look at [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) -> `Ctrl` + `F` -> `media-type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label for the type of content the requests contains.  Another name for the values would be [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types). (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)

For example, If you were downloading a `png` the response from the server would include the header `Content-Type: image/png`